# $\sum \dfrac{n^k}{2^n} (k\in \mathbb{N})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I think I solve it but I want some verify.
First I take $k=n$ and rewrote the series.
$\sum \dfrac{n^{n}}{2^{n}}$ and I apply Root Test. And in the end I got:
$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{n}{2}=\infty >1$ So that, series is divergent for $k=n$
And then, I assume that $k<n$
I applied Ratio Test and I got:
$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{1}{2}\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) ^{k}$ So I thought that, k<n in this respect I wrote this inequality:
$\dfrac{1}{2}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }1< \lim _{n-\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) ^{k} <\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) ^{n}$ So, I conclude that limit of second term must be between $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\dfrac{e}{2}$. My question is was it true? Or can I bound more clearly because $e/2$ is like $1.35...$ which means the inequality does not always give us convergent series.

Comment: $k$ is dependent on $n$?

Comment: Does not mention but instead. $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and constant.

Comment: Here your $\sum$ varies over $k$. Hence your $n$ is a constant throughout the summation. So you cannot assume $k=n$. For example you are trying to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{2^2}$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^k}{2^3}$ e.t.c

Comment: What do you mean by n is a constant?

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* take $k=n$ because $k$ is an up-front given, *costant* number from $\mathbb N$.

You *can* apply the ratio test, because

$$\frac{(n+1)^k/2^{n+1}}{n^k/2^n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\to\frac{1}{2}<1\text{ as }n\to\infty$$

(note $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ so $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\to 1^k=$ as $k$ is *fixed*.

As a way how to convince yourself that this is a correct view at the things, try to solve the same problem for some *concrete* $k$, e.g. $k=2$, $k=3$, $k=4$ ... and then notice that the logic of the solution doesn't really depend on $k$.

Comment: Oh, I understood very clearly, thanks! I'll try your suggestion.